# Getting trouble in showing marker on google map when using ios wrapper app ( web-view ) in js

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps

I am getting a problem in showing marker on map in wrapper app of ios as web-view, the markers are shown in an android browser as well as wrapper app ( web view ), but an only empty map is shown in ios web view. One thing more that the markers are shown in ios safari browser but not on web-view.

Please help me solving this issue.

Comment: Hey, I got the solution myself, I just changed the path of map icons in my map service used, and also saved the image icon of green and red marker into my folder, previously I was calling the image from https:// which was not recognized by wrapper app.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was also facing this kind of issue previously. Good job.